# Delete log files on IIS hosted website after certain days

Tags: iis, log-files

I want to delete log files created by my Silverlight application on IIS in a way that the server should check log files older than "n" number of days and delete them automatically.

Is there any configuration in IIS that can do this task or I should write my own utility for it?

Comment: When you think your question is answered, you should mark a question as the right answer. Doing so will make the question apear as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration switch I'm aware of. You can use the following Powershell script to delete logfiles older than 7 Days in C:\WIN2003\system32\LogFiles\SMTPSVC1 and C:\WIN2003\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1.

```
dir C:\WIN2003\system32\LogFiles\SMTPSVC1 |? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7)} | del
dir C:\WIN2003\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1 |? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7)} | del
```

Then start this as a planned task once every day. Run the command `C:\WIN2003\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file C:\Batch\cleanupLogfiles.ps1` in `C:\WIN2003\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` dir. For this example I assuemed your windows is installed in `C:\WIN2003` and your script is `C:\Batch\cleanupLogfiles.ps1`

Comment: Jon, thanks for the answer.. but my requirement is to automatically delete log files(created by application in a folder on website's virtual directory) without any intervention of a user/admin.

Comment: See update above

Comment: @asif Any more questions?